# Missing a leading zero in closed questions (in app)

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

As shown in the below screenshot, the minutes field doesn't have a leading zero for a minute count under ten.

[image]

I am using Android 4.3, and my app version is 0.1.65.

Comment: You need to plug your phone in... ;-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards And check his voicemail. As Sheldon Cooper would say... "Aren't you going to check your messages? ... You have to check your messages, the leaving of a message is one half of a social contract which is completed by the checking of the message. If that contract breaks down then all social contracts break down and we descend into anarchy."

Comment: Maybe the low battery is why it is dropping zeroes. :P

Comment: Sheldon would absolutely detest me @animuson ;) And yeah, the one day that I leave my charging cord at home...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.66 coming out later tonight, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I'll resolve this one as well tonight upon verification.